# Proving that a given polynomial is a constant multiple of a Legendre Polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n\ge1$ such that

$$\int_{-1}^1 (x^k)p(x)\,dx = 0$$

for $k = 0,1,2,3, \ldots, (n-1)$.

Show that $p(x) = cP_n(x)$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Hint: the legendre polynomials form an orthogonal basis of increasing degree.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that. I'm just not able to link it to the problem'

Comment: Expand $p$ as linear combination of the legendre polynomials and use that $p$ is orthogonal to polynomials of degree $\le n-1$ ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just not getting it

Comment: Never mind, I got it